# What is the best way to optimize this for loop for speed? (pandas, BS objects.)

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I have a pandas dataframe/series with a URL in each row to create a Beautiful Soup object from and scrape data from within. However, the loop is extremely slow and running my current loop would take many hours to complete as there are over 21,000 rows. Could this be optimized through apply or numpy?

```
count = 0
url = data['review_link']


for link in url:
    url = "http://{}".format(link)
    req = requests.get(url)
    best = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html')
    
    reviews = best.find_all('div', {'class' : 'review-detail'})
    
    for review in reviews:

        entry = {
            'artist' : safeFindText(review, 'ul', {'class' : 'artist-links artist-list single-album-tombstone__artist-links'}),
            'bnm' : safeFindText(review, 'p', {'class' : 'bnm-txt'}),
            'title' : safeFindText(review, 'h1', {'class' : 'single-album-tombstone__review-title'}),
            'score' : safeFindText(review, 'span', {'class' : 'score'}),
            'label' : safeFindText(review, 'li', {'class' : 'labels-list__item'}),
            'year' : safeFindText(review, 'span', {'class' : 'single-album-tombstone__meta-year'}),
            'author' : safeFindText(review, 'a', {'class' : 'authors-detail__display-name'}),
            'author_title' : safeFindText(review, 'span', {'class' : 'authors-detail__title'}),
            'genre' : safeFindText(review, 'a', {'class' : 'genre-list__link'}),
            'review_timestamp' : safeFindText(review, 'time', {'class' : 'pub-date'}),
            'review_abstract' : safeFindText(review, 'div', {'class' : 'review-detail__abstract'}),
            'review_text' : safeFindText(review,'div', {'class' : 'clearfix flex-md'})
            
            
                                   }
        pitchfork_dicts.append(entry)
        if count % 10 == 0:
            print("{} rows completed".format(count))
    count += 1
```

Comment: The actual looping is probably not the bottleneck, `.apply` wouldn't make an appreciable difference, indeed, it might be slightly slower.  `req = requests.get(url)` is likely the bottleneck, not looping over the dataframe. Or maybe whatever is going on in `safeFindText`. It's also no clear how you would use `numpy` here, it seems like you are simply extracting text data from websites, `numpy` is for code that would be expressed in terms of numeric operations on multidimensional arrays, linear algebra etc

Comment: You could make multiple requests to the API concurrently if that is your bottleneck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your program is sitting idle while requests is waiting for a response.  Since waiting for network IO is likely the bottlenext, I don't think apply or numpy are going to give you much speed up.  The two optimizations I can think of would be to either use a ThreadPool that takes care of doing all of the requests, while your main loop chugs through its list.  Or to use async to make the requests asynchronously so that while it's waiting on the responses, you can carry on with the list.

For the thread pool, you could create a Thread safe queue that your main thread pushes to. And then a thread pool of threads that pop off the next item and makes the request and process the result.